# Refresh view or activity on android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 1 activity that receives a json object from the server (database) and every activity called view (`TableLayout` but in `ScrollView`) automatically updates. But when I delete the data in the database (from current activity or directly from the database), the layout won't update.

I have tried to use the `removeView` method, call `setContentView` 'again' and re-initialize the layout, and at last I used `startActivity` and `finish` methods. But I think that will be weird if used it with something like `setInterval` method (but on Android) every 10 second.

Anyone know how to refresh view or activity without user noticing that the view has been refresh?

Thank you for reply and sorry if I was wrong. Just let me know the mistake that I made. I search for 1 full day on Google but didn't find a solution.

I am using Android 2.2 on testing and Linux OS emulator and here is my code:

```
package com.player;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

import com.maestro.Mylist.SideMenuClick;
import com.maestro.libs.Functions;
import com.maestro.libs.SQLiteDatabaseConnector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Playlist extends Activity {
private int page = 0;
private TableLayout tblContainer;
private int totalPage;

private String selectedItemIndex;
private TableRow selectedItem;
private Drawable rowColor;

// info to request page
private String roomName;
private String serverAddress;
private String playerUsername;
private String layoutUsername;

private Bundle stateTmp;

/**
 * 
 */
public Playlist() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public void getSong(){
    this.tblContainer = new TableLayout(this);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(this.serverAddress + "/index.php?m=playlist&a=list&room=" + this.roomName + 
            "&p=" + page + "&ax=ok");
    Functions.showAlert(this, this.serverAddress + "/index.php?m=playlist&a=list&room=" + this.roomName + 
            "&p=" + page + "&ax=ok");

    try{
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        // httpClient.notify();
        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = ht.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        try {
            JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(builder.toString());

            for(int i=1, j=0; i<obj.length(); i++, j++){
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Functions.showAlert(getRef(), arg0.getTag().toString());
                        selectedItem = (TableRow) arg0;
                        rowColor = arg0.getBackground();
                        arg0.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFA500);

                        selectedItemIndex = arg0.getTag().toString();
                        showDialog(0);
                    }
                });

                if((j % 2) == 0){
                    tr.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ffff);
                }
                tr.setTag(obj.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));

                TextView td = new TextView(this);
                td.setText(obj.getJSONObject(i).getString("songtitle"));
                td.setTextSize(30);
                td.setTextColor(0xff000000);
                tr.addView(td, 350, 40);

                TextView td2 = new TextView(this);
                td2.setText(obj.getJSONObject(i).getString("artist"));
                td2.setTextSize(30);
                td2.setTextColor(0xff000000);
                tr.addView(td2, 350, 40);

                this.tblContainer.addView(tr);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }catch(ClientProtocolException cpe){
        Functions.showAlert(this, cpe.toString());

    }catch(IOException e){
        Functions.showAlert(this, e.toString());

    }

}


/**
 * 
 */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.stateTmp = savedInstanceState;

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setTitle("Maestro - Playlist");
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

    // get room name(location)
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        Bundle tmp = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(tmp != null){
            this.roomName = tmp.getString("room_name");
            this.serverAddress = tmp.getString("server_address");
            this.playerUsername = tmp.getString("player_username");
            this.layoutUsername = tmp.getString("layout_username");
        }
    }

    /*SideMenuClick changeMenu = new SideMenuClick();
    ImageButton sideMenuSonglist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.songlist);
    sideMenuSonglist.setOnClickListener(changeMenu);

    ImageButton sideMenuKeyControl = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.keycontrol);
    sideMenuKeyControl.setOnClickListener(changeMenu);

    ImageButton sideMenuMylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    sideMenuMylist.setOnClickListener(changeMenu);

    getSong();
    ScrollView sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.listcontainer);
    sc.addView(this.tblContainer);

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagedesc);
    txt.setText((this.page+1) + " / " + this.totalPage);
    txt.setTextColor(0xff000000);

    ImageButton next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(changeMenu);

    ImageButton prev = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev);
    prev.setOnClickListener(changeMenu);*/

    drawLayout(true);
}

public void drawLayout(boolean isFirst){
    if(isFirst == true){
        // getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // setTitle("Maestro - Playlist");
    }


    SideMenuClick changeMenu = new SideMenuClick();
    ImageButton sideMenuSonglist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.songlist);
    sideMenuSonglist.setOnClickListener(changeMenu);

    ImageButton sideMenuKeyControl = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.keycontrol);
    sideMenuKeyControl.setOnClickListener(changeMenu);

    ImageButton sideMenuMylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    sideMenuMylist.setOnClickListener(changeMenu);

    getSong();
    ScrollView sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.listcontainer);
    sc.addView(this.tblContainer);

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagedesc);
    txt.setText((this.page+1) + " / " + this.totalPage);
    txt.setTextColor(0xff000000);

    ImageButton next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(changeMenu);

    ImageButton prev = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev);
    prev.setOnClickListener(changeMenu);
}

public Context getRef(){
    return this;
}

public void changeActivity(int layoutId){
    Intent newActivity = new Intent();
    newActivity.putExtra("room_name", this.roomName);
    newActivity.putExtra("server_address", this.serverAddress);
    newActivity.putExtra("player_username", this.playerUsername);
    newActivity.putExtra("layoyt_username", this.layoutUsername);

    if(R.id.songlist == layoutId){
        newActivity.setClass(this, ListSongs.class);
        startActivity(newActivity);

    }else if(R.id.keycontrol == layoutId){
        newActivity.setClass(this, KeyControl.class);
        startActivity(newActivity);

    }else if(R.id.mylist == layoutId){
        newActivity.setClass(this, Mylist.class);
        startActivity(newActivity);

    }else if(R.id.prev == layoutId){
        if(page > 0){
            page--;
        }

        ScrollView sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.listcontainer);
        sc.removeView(this.tblContainer);

        getSong();

        sc.addView(this.tblContainer);
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagedesc);
        txt.setText((this.page+1) + " / " + this.totalPage);


    }else if(R.id.next == layoutId){
        if(this.page < this.totalPage){
            page++;
        }

        ScrollView sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.listcontainer);
        sc.removeView(this.tblContainer);

        getSong();

        sc.addView(this.tblContainer);

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagedesc);
        txt.setText((this.page+1) + " / " + this.totalPage);
    }
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

    ImageButton ib0 = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.back);
    ib0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selectedItem.setBackgroundDrawable(rowColor);
            dismissDialog(0);
        }
    });

    ImageButton ib1 = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.del);
    ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            Toast.makeText(getRef(), selectedItemIndex, 60000);
            HttpClient ajax = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serverAddress + "/index.php?m=playlist&a=del&room=" + roomName + "&to=" + playerUsername + 
                    "&username=" + layoutUsername + "&id=" + selectedItemIndex);

            //Functions.showAlert(getRef(), serverAddress + "/index.php?m=playlist&a=del&room=" + roomName + "&to=" + playerUsername + 
            //      "&username=" + layoutUsername + "&id=" + selectedItemIndex);
            try {
                ajax.execute(httpGet);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            selectedItem.setBackgroundDrawable(rowColor);

            dismissDialog(0);

            // ScrollView sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.listcontainer);
            // sc.removeView(tblContainer);
            // sc.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            // sc.destroyDrawingCache();
            // tblContainer.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            // setContentView(R.layout.playlist);
            // setContentView(R.layout.playlist);
            // drawLayout(false);
            Intent newActivity = new Intent();
            newActivity.putExtra("room_name", roomName);
            newActivity.putExtra("server_address", serverAddress);
            newActivity.putExtra("player_username", playerUsername);
            newActivity.putExtra("layoyt_username", layoutUsername);
            newActivity.setClass(getRef(), Playlist.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
            finish();

            // getSong();
            // sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.listcontainer);
            // tblContainer = new TableLayout(getRef());
            // sc.addView(tblContainer);
        }
    });

    ImageButton ib2 = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.top);
    ib2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            Toast.makeText(getRef(), selectedItemIndex, 60000);
            HttpClient ajax = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serverAddress + "/index.php?m=playlist&a=top&room=" + roomName + "&to=" + playerUsername + 
                    "&username=" + layoutUsername + "&id=" + selectedItemIndex);

            try {
                ajax.execute(httpGet);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            selectedItem.setBackgroundDrawable(rowColor);

            dismissDialog(0);

            ScrollView sc = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.listcontainer);
            sc.removeView(tblContainer);
            tblContainer = new TableLayout(getRef());

            getSong();

            sc.addView(tblContainer);
        }
    });


    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(170, 90));
    layout.setMinimumWidth(0);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(layout);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selectedItem.setBackgroundDrawable(rowColor);
            dismissDialog(0);
        }});

    return alertDialog;
}

public class SideMenuClick implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // changeList();
        changeActivity(arg0.getId());
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views in Android have an Invalidate and PostInvalidate method which will at some point call the OnDraw method.

So if you have populated a View with some data, you can make it redraw itself by invoking one of those two.